# Comparing multiple column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 columns, let's say A, B, C and D. Is there an easy way to create a where clause that will check if any of these 4 have a different value? In my case, every column has to be the same value, but if any of these 4 are not, the query must return the record. I know there is a hard way with OR, but is there an more gentle way?

Comment: How would you want to treat `NULL` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably go with @Littlefoot's approach

```
where not( a = b and b = c and c = d )
```

The other approach would be to use the `greatest` and `least` functions

```
where greatest(a, b, c, d) != least(a, b, c, d)
```

Of course, if any of your columns are nullable, you may have to tweak the logic depending on what you want to happen since `null` is neither equal to nor unequal to any other value.

Answer (score 1):

`AND`, instead of `OR`?

```
SQL> with test (a, b, c, d) as
  2    (select 1, 2, 2, 4 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 2, 2, 2 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 1, 1, 4 from dual
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from test
  8  where not (a = b and b = c and c = d);

         A          B          C          D
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          2          4
         1          1          1          4

SQL>
```

Comment: I believe the goal is to return the other two rows so you'd want `where not( a = b ...`.

Comment: Ah! I was mislead by "every column has to be the same value". Thank you, @Justin, fixed.